# How to get only sign in integer value by objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I'm wondering a way that get only sign in integer value.

How to get a sign in integer value?

Please your help..

what I want is)

```
int value =  100;  ====>  result :  1
int value = -100;  ====>  result : -1
int value =    0;  ====>  result :  0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trivial.

```
int signum(int n) { return (n < 0) ? -1 : (n > 0) ? +1 : 0; }
```

Comment: What about signbit macro from math.h?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: `signbit` will only tell you whether the number is negative, whereas this function will return whether the input is negative, zero, or positive. Zero is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: @larsmans - that makes sense - but just been checking into C99 (probably the same or close enough) standard - looks like positive and negative zeros are down to the implementation. (6.2.6.3)

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Yes, whether an arithmetic type can contain positive and negative zeroes is implementation-dependent, however *mathematically* speaking, zero is neither positive nor negative.

Answer (score 4):

Use `signbit(x)` declared in math.h

Answer (score 2):

```
(int)signOfInteger:(int)integer {

        return (integer > 0) - (integer < 0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (int)signOfInteger:(int)integer {
    if (integer != 0) {
        integer = (integer < 0) ? -1 : +1;
    }
    return integer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

signOfIntegerOrFloat = (x-fabs(x)) > 0.0 ? 1 : ((x-fabs(x)) < 0.0 ? -1 : 0)

float = fabsf ( float ) - for float

double = fabs ( double ) - for double

long double = fabsl (long double) - for long double